# Why am I getting "uri:/carbon/admin/login.jsp, error:required token is missing from the request" when trying to log into WSO2 APIM?

Tags: wso2, csrf, wso2-api-manager

I configured my cluster in AWS for WSO2 API Manager, with load balancers for each section: The store, the publisher, the gateway managers and the gateway workers.

However, when I try to log into the Store, the Publisher or Carbon, with the correct username and password, I get the following error in the logs:

```
ARN - JavaLogger potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted
(user:<anonymous>, ip:10.0.1.125, method:HEAD, uri:/carbon/admin/login.jsp,
error:required token is missing from the request)
```

That's all the information the log gives me, and I know for sure the user/pass is correct. Why can't I log in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only posted this question for share the answer, because I couldn't find anything about it on Google.

My problem was that the load balancer was configure to distribute the requests evenly among it's instances. So, when I tried to log in, the request always was sent to a different node, which by definition is a CSRF attack.

As soon as I allowed those requests to be sticky, so a login request from a node goes to itself, the log in works.

Comment: Sticky sessions are needed. Otherwise, lb will route requests to several nodes and it would fail the login request as well as other requests you made to the server.  You can find the configurations in the guide - https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+NGINX